# How to remove components from a react-admin app based on the route?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have created a user register page on the react-admin template, but when it's rendered, the sidebar and appbar are being rendered as well.
The default login page in the template gets rendered without these 2 components.
How do I configure the app so that the register page also gets rendered without the sidebar and appbar?

MyLayout.js

```
// in src/MyLayout.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withStyles, MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
    AppBar,
    Menu,
    Notification,
    Sidebar,
    setSidebarVisibility,
} from 'react-admin';




const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        zIndex: 1,
        minHeight: '100vh',
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        position: 'relative',
    },
    appFrame: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        overflowX: 'auto',
    },
    contentWithSidebar: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    content: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        flexGrow: 2,
        padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        marginTop: '4em',
        paddingLeft: 5,
    },
});



class MyLayout extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.setSidebarVisibility(true);
    }

    render() {
        const {
            children,
            classes,
            dashboard,
            isLoading,
            logout,
            open,
            title,
        } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <div className={classes.appFrame}>
                    <AppBar title={title} open={open} logout={logout} color="primary"/>
                    <main className={classes.contentWithSidebar}>
                        <Sidebar>
                            <Menu logout={logout} hasDashboard={!!dashboard} />
                        </Sidebar>
                        <div className={classes.content}>
                            {children}
                        </div>
                    </main>
                    <Notification />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

MyLayout.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.node]),
    dashboard: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.func,
        PropTypes.string,
    ]),
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    logout: 'componentPropType',
    setSidebarVisibility: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ isLoading: state.admin.loading > 0 });
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setSidebarVisibility })(withStyles(styles)(MyLayout));
```

register.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { propTypes, reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';

import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import LockIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Lock';

import { Notification, translate, userLogin } from 'react-admin';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import dataProvider from './dataProvider';


const styles = theme => ({
    main: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        minHeight: '100vh',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        background: 'url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x900)',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
    },
    card: {
        minWidth: 300,
        marginTop: '6em',
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: '1em',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    icon: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    hint: {
        marginTop: '1em',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: theme.palette.grey[500],
    },
    form: {
        padding: '0 1em 1em 1em',
    },
    input: {
        marginTop: '1em',
    },
    actions: {
        padding: '0 1em 1em 1em',
    },
});

// see http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/material-ui/
const renderInput = ({
    meta: { touched, error } = {},
    input: { ...inputProps },
    ...props
}) => (
    <TextField
        error={!!(touched && error)}
        helperText={touched && error}
        {...inputProps}
        {...props}
        fullWidth
    />
);

class Register extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            submitted: false
        };


        //this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleFirstNameChange = this.handleFirstNameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleLastNameChange = this.handleLastNameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);  

    }

    handleFirstNameChange(e){
        this.setState({firstName:e.target.value});
    }
    handleLastNameChange(e) {
        this.setState({ lastName: e.target.value });
    }
    handleEmailChange(e) {
        this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
    }
    handlePasswordChange(e) {
        this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
    }




    register = () => {
        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = this.state;
        //console.log(data);
        //console.log(firstName);

        dataProvider('CREATE', 'user/register', { 'data': { 'fname': firstName, 'lname': lastName, 'email': email, 'password': password } });

        /*dataProvider('CREATE', 'user/register', { data: {
                 fname: 1, lname: 5, email: test, password: 1234
            } });*/
    }

    render() {
        const { classes, handleSubmit, isLoading, translate } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.main}>
                <Card className={classes.card}>
                    <div className={classes.avatar}>
                        <Avatar className={classes.icon}>
                            <LockIcon />
                        </Avatar>
                    </div>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.register)}>
                        <div className={classes.hint}></div>
                        <div className={classes.form}>
                            <div className={classes.input}>
                                <Field
                                    name="firstName"
                                    component={renderInput}
                                    label={'First Name'}
                                    disabled={isLoading}
                                    value={this.state.firstName} 
                                    onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className={classes.input}>
                                <Field
                                    name="lastName"
                                    component={renderInput}
                                    label={'Last Name'}
                                    disabled={isLoading}
                                    value={this.state.lastName} 
                                    onChange={this.handleLastNameChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className={classes.input}>
                                <Field
                                    name="email"
                                    component={renderInput}
                                    label={'Email'}
                                    disabled={isLoading}
                                    value={this.state.email} 
                                    onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className={classes.input}>
                                <Field
                                    name="password"
                                    component={renderInput}
                                    label={translate('ra.auth.password')}
                                    type="password"
                                    disabled={isLoading}
                                    value={this.state.password} 
                                    onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <CardActions className={classes.actions}>
                            <Button
                                variant="raised"
                                type="submit"
                                color="primary"
                                disabled={isLoading}
                                className={classes.button}
                                fullWidth
                            >
                                {isLoading && (
                                    <CircularProgress size={25} thickness={2} />
                                )}
                                {'Register'}
                            </Button>
                        </CardActions>
                        <CardActions className={classes.actions}>
                            <Button
                                variant="raised"
                                color="secondary"
                                disabled={isLoading}
                                className={classes.button}
                                fullWidth
                                >
                                <Link to={{pathname: "/login"}} style={{textDecoration: 'none', color:'#fff'}} >Sign In</Link>
                            </Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </form>

                </Card>
                <Notification />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Register.propTypes = {
    ...propTypes,
    authProvider: PropTypes.func,
    classes: PropTypes.object,
    previousRoute: PropTypes.string,
    translate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    userLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ isLoading: state.admin.loading > 0 });

const enhance = compose(
    translate,
    reduxForm({
        form: 'signIn',
        validate: (values, props) => {
            const errors = {};
            const { translate } = props;
            if (!values.fname) {
                errors.fname = translate('ra.validation.required');
            }
            if (!values.lname) {
                errors.lname = translate('ra.validation.required');
            }
            if (!values.email) {
                errors.email = translate('ra.validation.required');
            }
            if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email) ) {
                errors.email = 'A valid email is required';
            }
            if (!values.password) {
                errors.password = translate('ra.validation.required');
            }
            return errors;
        },
    }),
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        { userLogin }
    ),
    withStyles(styles)
);

export default enhance(Register);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will use a customRoute to add your register page to router. You can add a 'noLayout' for not displaying appbar and sidebar

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Admin.md#customroutes